# Trouble with time requirement for url opening using python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have designed a python program that will open a url and fetch data like email and numbers from that url. 
Main problem is that it is very slow, I want to know if there is a way to increase speed of fetching data from url.

Some specifications:

1. Program is in python.
2. I am using urllib2.open for opening url
3. beautifulsoup for searching and fetching

> opener = urllib2.build_opener() 
>   opener.addheaders = [('User-agent','Mozilla/5.0')]

```
with open('Labgodata.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for line in reader:
            sleep(0.2)
            getdata(line['URL'])
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing now? without seeing what exactly your program is doing its hard to say exactly.

but

In general try to limit calls to urls, if your fetching lots of data from a page try to grab everything you'll need at once and save it to a variable, that way if your making multiple calls it takes less time to grab it from memory then to make a request for a web page.

Comment: I am doing this. I am storing all data in a variable. But it is still very slow